# Transfer data from guest account on registration

Tags: meteor

I'm building a task management app that can be used without signing in (with `artwells:meteor-accounts-guest`). When the user registers an account, I want the guest account's tasks to transfer over to the new account.

I tried using `Accounts.onCreateUser` to do this, but the id of the guest account is not obviously available inside the callback (`Meteor.user()` is null).

How can I accomplish this, without having to trust the client code to report its own guest account id to the server?

Comment: Have you thought about creating the new account from their old account with a `method`?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. I'd probably go about storing the guest accounts data with local storage calls, saving the guest account data locally whenever you load the template wherein which a user can register for a full account.

You can then pull that data when you call onCreateUser.

You could also do what @kyll mentioned and create a server side method for creating a new user. You'd just have to make sure you can pass the guest account id in order to select the proper guest account document.

Comment: I'm worried that storing the guest account id on the client side would create a security hole: the client could set the guest account id to the id of a target account, then register a new account and have the tasks from the target account be transferred to the new account.

Answer (score -1):

I made a mistake: the reason `Meteor.user()` was null in `Accounts.onCreateUser` was that `accounts-guest` wasn't even loaded!

I was able to access both user ids in `Accounts.onCreateUser` in the end:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  currentUser = Meteor.user()
  if (currentUser.profile !== undefined && currentUser.profile.guest === true)
      Tasks.update({user: currentUser._id}, {$set: {user: user._id}}, {multi: true})
  if (options.profile)
      user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```